# Can a perl regex use parens but skip backreferencing on them?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have this regex:

```
@disks = $sysconfig =~ /(\d+)\.\d+:(\s+[\w.\/]+){5}\s+\((\w+)\)/ig
```

If there were only one line that matched, I'd get something like

```
1835 x @array
1836  35
1837  ' 520B/sect'
1838  'KXG813JF'
```

It matches:

1. the first digits in the string
2. the fifth copy of the "spaces then alphanumeric-periods-and-slashes" and
3. the alphanumeric string at the end

I don't want to backreference #2 above and clutter my array with it, but I also don't want to write out that repeating pattern when what I've got is a more concise regex (to look at).

Is there a way to say "don't backreference this piece" or should I just deal with it when I parse the array out into something more usable by my program?

Comment: “Backreferencing” in regexes describes a term where you reference a matching group *within* the regex. Take a look at [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html). That's a way more complicated topic than your problem. It's even in the Tag description of backreferences. An example: `/(\d+) \1/` matches a digit that occurs twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use the non-capturing group construct: `(?:` ... `)`.

You even should use this *by default*, unless you need backreferences or capturing.

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't know about "by default"--my "default" is "short patterns without too many groups." But yeah, once a pattern gets nontrivial, it's a pretty good idea not to capture groups you don't want. (At which point the groups you *do* want should probably be *named*...)

Comment: @Kyle I mean I prefer using non-capturing groups over capturing ones when I only need to group constructs but don't actually need to extract the value, since the regex engine should be faster in this case (it has less work to do). Of course, once the regex gets nontrivial, using named patterns and the `x` modifier are good practices.